# Collision of CharacterBody2D and StaticBody2D not triggering

Tags: game-engine, game-development, collision, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to trigger a print when CharacterBody2D collides with StaticBody2D. I'm very new to Godot please bear with me

I got 3 scenes *game_level*, *CharacterBody2D (player)*, *StaticBody2D (item)*. In game_level, I instantiated child Player and Item

I currently attached this script to the StaticBody2D (item):

```
extends StaticBody2D

func _ready():
    print("ready")
    

func _on_StaticBody2D_body_entered(body):
    print("Static body collided with: ", body.name)
```

I tried changing Collision Layer & Mask for both the CharacterBody2D and StaticBody2D as follows:

Just bumped but no prints

```
CharacterBody2D            || StaticBody2D
Collision>Layer = 1        || Collision>Layer = 1
Collision>Mask = 1         || Collision>Mask = 1
```

Just passed through but no prints

```
CharacterBody2D            || StaticBody2D
Collision>Layer = 1        || Collision>Layer = 2
Collision>Mask = 1         || Collision>Mask = 2
```

Just bumped but no prints

```
CharacterBody2D            || StaticBody2D
Collision>Layer = 1        || Collision>Layer = 2
Collision>Mask = 1 & 2     || Collision>Mask = 1 & 2
```

*Godot Version:* `Godot_v4.0.1-stable_win64`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Godot `Node`s have signals, which you can connect form the editor or from code. You need to connect the signal for them to work.

**I know you didn't connect the `body_entered` signal of your `StaticBody2D`.**

*Making a method with the name that matches the that Godot would generate - in this case `_on_StaticBody2D_body_entered` - does not work.*

You can see if Godot recognized that a method has a signal connected because it shows a green icon on the left of the method declaration in the code editor.

Please refer to [Using Signals](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/step_by_step/signals.html)

---

**I know you didn't connect the `body_entered` signal of your `StaticBody2D`... Because `StaticBody2D` does not have a `body_entered` signal.**

It is possible to work around that. I have outlined some approaches [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/204775/10408). And I won't repeat them here.

With that said, my recommendation is to not use an `StaticBody2D` but an `Area2D` instead.

If you need it to be an `StaticBody2D`, then I suggest adding a child `Area2D` to the `StaticBody2D` and use that to detect the collisions (which is one of the options I mention [elsewhere](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/204775/10408)).

---

For completeness I'll also mention that you can detect what the `CharacterBody2D` ran into. Like this:

```
for index in get_slide_collision_count():
    var collision := get_slide_collision(index)
    prints(collision.get_collider())
```

Which should be sufficient for the case of a `CharacterBody2D` and a `StaticBody2D` that does not move※, because if the `StaticBody2D` does not move, it won't run into the `CharacterBody2D` (in other words the collision would be result of the motion of the `CharacterBody2D`).

※: The recommended way to do moving platforms in Godot 4 is with an `AnimatableBody2D` which are `StaticBody2D`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. So right now I can I either detect collision from `CharacterBody2D` or change node type of `StaticBody2D` to `Area2D ` (I did this one using `func _on_body_entered(body): print("Area2D collided with: ", body.name)`). Just a follow-up question, Which one is better? detect colliding objects via the character or the area? Thanks again

Comment: @FurtiveStranger First know that the `CharacterBody2D` wont detect a collision of something that runs into it (e.g. a ``RigidBody2D`). So for the case of a bullet or an enemy attack. Second, similarly to adding a `Area2D` to an `StaticBody2D` you can add an `Area2D` to the `CharacterBody2D`. From there it is an architecture question. If you handle everything on the `CharacterBody2D` the code might become large and hard to work with, also when you change the other scene you might have to update the code on the `CharacterBody2D` too. So often handling it on the other side is better.